# Implementing Searchable, a search trait for Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, searchable

I was trying to implement a searchable function using Searchable, a search trait for Laravel by nicolaslopezj, i have used the following code. But it doesn't seem to work. If there are only two records in the database it show the records but if more then two records it doesn't search.

Model: Contact.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Nicolaslopezj\Searchable\SearchableTrait;


class Contact extends Model
{
    use SearchableTrait;

        protected $searchable = [
        'columns' => [
            'contacts.first_name' => 10,
            'contacts.last_name' => 10,
        ]];
}
```

Controller: SearchController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Nicolaslopezj\Searchable\SearchableTrait;
use View;
use App\Contact;
use App\Tag;
use App\Project;
use App\User;
//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function findContact(Request $request)
        {
            return Contact::search($request->get('cname'))->get();
        }

         public function contactPrefetch()
        {
           $all_contacts= Contact::All();
           return \Response::json($all_contacts);
        }
}
```

View: show.blade.php

```
<script src="{{asset('global/js/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js')}}"></script>
 <script src="{{asset('global/js/pages/base_tables_datatables.js')}}"></script>


<div class="input-group input-medium " style="float: right; padding-top: 3px; ">
                            <input type="search" name="cname" class="form-control search-input" placeholder="search contact" autocomplete="off" >


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <!-- Typeahead.js Bundle -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.11.1/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            // Set the Options for "Bloodhound" suggestion engine
            var engine = new Bloodhound({
                prefetch: '/find_contact_all',
                remote: {
                    url: '/find_contact?q=%QUERY%',
                    wildcard: '%QUERY%'
                },
                datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace('cname'),
                // queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
            });

            $(".search-input").typeahead({
                hint: true,
                highlight: true,
                minLength: 1
            }, {
                source: engine.ttAdapter(),

                name: 'contact',
                display: function(data) {
                                          return data.first_name + ' '+ data.last_name ;
                                   },

                templates: {
                    empty: [
                        '<a class="list-group-item"> Agent not found.</a>'
                    ],
                    header: [
                        '<div class="list-group search-results-dropdown">'
                    ],
                    suggestion: function (data) {
                               return '<a href="/home/contact/profile/'+data.id+'" class="list-group-item">' + data.first_name + ' ' + data.first_name +  '</a>'


              }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('find_contact', 'SearchController@findContact');
Route::get('find_contact_all', 'SearchController@contactPrefetch');
```

Comment: i think it is a bug of typeahead plugin. I had some issues in past with typeahead. check in network tab if your are receiving any data from server or not?

Comment: ya all the data is being fetched from server i have checked it, but when i type any name it doesn't display any.  @MuhammadInaamMunir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the package to your "composer.json" file and "composer update"[update your composer]
"nicolaslopezj/searchable": "1.*"